# How to Play Poker on many tables at the same time?

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-theory, poker-strategy, poker-tools

I am searching some web applications which makes it possible to play simultaneously Poker Texas Holdem, for instance in 9 tables.

Which online sites or applications are good for playing poker simultaneously? 
Any recommendations about setups, strategies and so on are also welcome.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Almost all online sites make it trivially easy to launch a new window per table.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer I have automatized Lord of Ultima to be played in 9 TTYs in Linux such that I wrote small scripts and put my computer run that script series randomly such that the detection system of the system could not detect me. However, I think here with a poker it is more important to have all acute screens at the top. So the system should highlight those tables where I have least time left. Is there any poker tables which indicate the time clearly and how many opponents before your turn? Other things may be there too which I have not considered. I am a newbie here.

Comment: So your intent is to create a tool that enables collusion by allowing you to simulate several users at once?

Comment: @ChrisFarmer No. I do not want to simulate. I cannot automate Poker playing. I would like to make it smooth for me to play at many tables simultaneously.

Comment: If you're a newbie, you should not attempt multi-tabling. It reduces your EV drastically.

Multi-tabling is for extremely experienced pros who want to extract the most profit out of micro-stakes at a fast rate.

Answer (score 3):

There's a big number of applications out there, ready to ease your massive multi-tabling such as [Table Droid](http://www.tabledroid.com) (as mentioned by @XVirtusX) or [Table Ninja](https://www.pokertracker.com/products/TableNinja/).

Keep in mind that these programs don't not do anything more than positioning your tables, open new ones and may/or not optimize your bets. Poker companies are *very picky to extra real-time information* like *remaining number of players* or *remaining time left to act*.

Talking about *pokerstars*, for example, there is a big list of *allowed / banned* software list [here](http://www.toolspoker.com/pokerstars/pokerstars-allowed-poker-tools/). The programs referenced above are *allowed*.

Most platforms do a very nice job opening and sorting off whatever number of tables you open, `including focusing any cascaded table window if there's action to be made`. The programs above are for the power users who playing, say, 20+ tables at once and action is rapid. Did you tried multi-tabling by what the platform is offering you?

Also, keep in mind that for 10+ tables you may need an additional higher resolution monitor, although that's opinion based.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly customizing hotkeys and layouts for automatic table placements on screen is of big help for anyone seriously considering multitabling. I recommend you to use automatic [Table Droid](http://www.tabledroid.com). It has all this features and it is free to use playing in microstakes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Pokerstars will allow you to play up to 5 play money tables at the same time. You could play on another site at the same time to add more. Most poker rooms will have a cap on the number of play money tables that you can play because you are not a paying customer of theirs and therefore you only get to use so much free bandwidth :)

Comment: i think _pokerstars_ allows you 8 tables maximum for play money (cash) and 4 for play money (zoom), which is indeed a bandwidth cap, at least for cash games